# Use Side-bar Nav in component

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular, angular2-template, angular2-directives

This is my code

```
<md-sidenav-layout>
    <left-nav></left-nav>
    <md-content >
      This is content
    </md-content>
</md-sidenav-layout>
```

And left-nav component contains template html with this code.

```
 <md-sidenav #left [opened]="true" mode="side" layout-padding>
      <h2>Left Sidenav.</h2>
    </md-sidenav>
```

The problem is sidebar is not working when I check the generated html code, it is something like this.

### Left Sidenav.

This is content

how can I generate code like below without extra tags even if I use component?

```
<md-sidenav-layout _nghost-pam-3="">

    <md-sidenav layout-padding="" mode="side" ng-reflect-mode="side" ng-reflect-_opened="true" class="md-sidenav-opened md-sidenav-side">
        <h2>Left Sidenav.</h2>
    </md-sidenav>

    <md-content layout-padding="">
         This is content
     </md-content> 

</md-sidenav-layout>
```

Comment: If you would be able to use plunker or jsfiddle to recreate the issue that would help us help you faster and easier